# Sending a "POST" request to send file data using actions from React-Router-Dom in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, fetch-api, submit

I am facing a problem with handling POST requests which contain "File type input" using Action from React-Router-Dom.
I am using `<From/>` component from React-Router-Dom also.

**Form Component:**

```
<Form method="post"> 
         <div>
          <label htmlFor="tradeLicensePhoto">Copy of trade license</label>
          <input
            id="tradeLicensePhoto"
            type="file"
            name="tradeLicensePhoto"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="profilePhoto">Profile Photo</label>
          <input
            id="profilePhoto"
            type="file"
            name="profilePhoto"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="coverPhoto">Cover Photo</label>
          <input
            id="coverPhoto"
            type="file"
            name="coverPhoto"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="frontIdPhoto">Front ID Photo</label>
          <input
            id="frontIdPhoto"
            type="file"
            name="frontIdPhoto"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="backIdPhoto">Back ID Photo</label>
          <input
            id="backIdPhoto"
            type="file"
            name="backIdPhoto"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button>{isSubmitting ? "Submitting...": "Save"}</button>
</Form>
```

**Action Function:**

```
export async function authenticationAction({ request }) {
 const data = await request.formData();
 const authData = {
  tradeLicensePhoto: data.get("tradeLicensePhoto"),
  profilePhoto: data.get("profilePhoto"),
  coverPhoto: data.get("coverPhoto"),
  frontIdPhoto: data.get("frontIdPhoto"),
  backIdPhoto: data.get("backIdPhoto"),
};
 const response = await fetch(
  `API-LINK`,
  {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(authData),
  }
);
 if (!response.ok) {
  throw json({ message: "Could not authenticate user." }, { status: 500 });
 }
}
```

> On the server side it is showing this error: *Cannot read property 'profilePhoto' of undefined*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, but I was able to fix it with `encType` attribute:

```
    <Form method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
```